# How an array passed in the object 1 per each passed member id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains several elements after that I created an object in which I passed this array as a value but it passed all the values as a single string.

```
var cars = \["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"\];
console.log(cars);
var test = Object.assign({}, cars);
console.log(test);

var anv = {
new1 : test,
id : "1.K"
}
console.log(anv);
```

The Output we are getting is this
[image]

But output we require after passing the array inside object

```
0:{id:"1.R", new1:"Saab"}
```

```
1:{id:"1.R", new1:"Volvo"}
```

```
2:{id:"1.R", new1:"BMW"}
```

I have tried the object assign method but not works for me

Comment: What object do you have right now. In expected you have 3 item with id as 1.R. but you have id as 1.K. Not sure. Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @CodeThing I mean I initialize a new instance of a MemberValue object like this
`var newObject = new data.MemberValue();` In this MemberValue object I have to pass name and value` {
  id : "1.K",
  car: cars }`
And the value of cars is in array 
`var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];`
Now what I have to do is to pass the create an object for each item in the list 
You can see the output we need in the above description

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the `.map` function to create an object for each item in the list

```js
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

const anv = cars.map(
  car => ({
    id: "1.K",
    car: car
  })
)

console.log(anv);
```

Comment: but I already have an object how can I map inside that object that will contain id:"1.k , car: "cars"

Comment: Hmmm... It is not clear from your wording here what you want to obtain. Your _question_ is clear on what you want, however: you list out clearly that you want an array, that has 3 objects inside it. This answer provides exactly that. If what you showed is not what you want, please add a clarification.

Comment: Ok so what I meant is I already have the object created inside that I have passed id: "1. k", car: cars but what happened their it takes as an array now I have to modify the same object in which instead of the array we pass each member value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Object.assign` at the beginning, you can first create the array of your desired output and then use `Object.assign`.

Here is a demo-

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var anv = [];

cars.forEach(item => {
  anv.push({
    new1: item,
    id: "1.K"
  })
})

var result = Object.assign({}, anv)
console.log(result)
```

Please let me know if I didn't get your use case.

Comment: I mean I initialize a new instance of a MemberValue object like this var newObject = new data.MemberValue(); In this MemberValue object I have to pass name and value` { id : "1.K", car: cars }` And the value of cars is in array var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; Now what I have to do is to pass the create an object for each item in the list You can see the output we need in the above description